# How do you get a Bitmap Image into a wpf ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, .net-3.5

This is what I have

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="22" Height="22"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Image is a System.Drawing.Bitmap image that I am getting from a Namespace.Resources.

I cannot get any image to show up in column no matter what I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert from the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` into an ImageSource, which is what WPF uses for images.  You can do this via [Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx):

```
// Include, in your class or elsewhere:
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

Bitmap image = LoadYourBitmap();

IntPtr hbitmap = image.GetHbitmap();
try
{
   var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
      hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
      Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
finally
{
    // Clean up the bitmap data
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
}
```

Comment: So I'm interested in this as I've been using another method to convert a `Bitmap` into a `BitmapSource`, initializing it from a MemoryStream (I get the image data as a Base64 encoded string, so it makes sense).  After running some tests, this method is much faster than mine (consistently 70% faster using 100 samples), but the memory usage continually increases as I call this method.  This does not happen with my method as I have spent some amount of time making sure that everything is cleaned up as quickly as possible (we had some memory issues initially).  Any idea why this is?

Comment: I'll be looking into it as well, so thanks either way.  It doesn't make much sense to me at a glance, but I see a ~30MB jump in my working set after converting a 320x240 image 100 times.

Comment: Ahhh, from the docs: *You are responsible for calling DeleteObject to free the memory used by the GDI bitmap object.*.  I assumed that calling Dispose would still do it, but this is not the case.  This code has a leak.  You will need to call DeleteObject each time you call GetHBitmap.  Otherwise it works great, thanks!

Comment: Yup, that's it.  The only thing I would add is to call DeleteObject in a finally block, but I know this is just example code.  Thanks again, this will speed up my code even if I have to create a dummy Bitmap to use it.

Comment: @Ed S.: There, just to be complete ;)